# SQL Server CONVERT and CAST not returning the correct date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-format

I have a table in SQL Server with a column `RGSTR_DATE` that is of `varchar(10)` data type, and it has values like `2016-01-23`, `1998-08-12`, etc...

I want to select and convert those values to `20160123`, `19980812`, etc...

I tried running these queries:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CAST(RGSTR_DATE AS DATE), 112) 
FROM [project].[dbo].[my_table];

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RGSTR_DATE, 112) 
FROM [project].[dbo].[my_table];
```

But the results that came back were still `2016-01-23`, `1998-08-12` etc...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean come back?  you aren't reading them into excel to view them are you?

Comment: I mean the results that appear in console at the bottom of SQL Server Management Studio still show the hyphenated format of the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cast(RGSTR_DATE as date),112)
```

Comment: This makes sense... cast RGSTR_DATE as a date then convert it to a VARCHAR with formatting 112

Comment: As a side effect this approach would protect you from erronous date-strings like `2016-13-05`. Replacing the hyphens as suggested by John Pasquet is faster, if you are sure about your date-values. Voted on both...

Comment: @Shnugo I agree, at first I liked John P's answer, but then reconsidered because I DON'T TRUST USERS.  They may be smart, but they do really dumb things

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, I'd prefer your approach too, due to the same reasons. Best was to store data with the appropriate data-type actually :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're converting a varchar to a date, but all you need to do is remove the hyphens.

```
SELECT REPLACE(RGSTR_DATE, '-', '')
FROM [project].[dbo].[my_table]
```